# How do I create a C Pointer in MacRuby?

Tags: c, macruby, scripting-bridge

I am working with a C Framework in MacRuby which has a structure

```
int CPhidget_getSerialNumber(CPhidgetHandle phid,int * serialNumber)
```

You can see the full documentation [here](http://www.phidgets.com/documentation/web/cdoc/group__phidcommon.html#gaa2ef0db106382a29692a0f1341b70fd) (if you are interested).

In MacRuby I have tried the following:

```
i = CPhidget_getSerialNumber(@encoder, nil)
```

The above gets me a number but not the serial number.

```
CPhidget_getSerialNumber(@encoder, i)
```

This gets me an error stating: expected instance of Pointer, got `0' (Fixnum) (TypeError) (which doesn't surprise me).

So my main question is: Is there an equivalent of a C Pointer in MacRuby?

Comment: The documentation you link to seems to be the documentation for the raw C library. How do you perform the foreign function calls?

Comment: I have a cocoa framework based off the C-API. The functions are all the same (apparently). I generated a bridge support file to access the constants in the header file and it _seems_ to be working. Here's the Cocoa 'guide' (http://www.phidgets.com/documentation/Tutorials/Getting_Started_Cocoa.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MacRuby has a Pointer class, which can stand in for a C pointer. So, you could do something like:

```
i = Pointer.new(:int)
CPhidget_getSerialNumber(@encoder, i)
```

Then, to extract the results from the pointer (i.e. dereference it), you use Ruby's array access syntax:

```
i[0] #=> value from CPhidget_getSerialNumber
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for your help Josh. I couldn't find any reference to the pointer class in Ruby docs or the Apple documentation. Just out of curiosity, do you know where the docs on it are?

Comment: It seems we haven't actually documented this yet (normally you'd be able to read the documentation using `macri`). If you'd like to file a bug requesting documentation, you can do so here: https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby/issues

Comment: Hi Josh, I will file the bug but I did end up finding a pointer class reference on the github wiki: https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby/wiki/Pointer-Class